# How to Disable a button in dataGridView which is not clickable(c# windows application)

Tags: c#, button, windows

I found many similar questions and answers but none help me to solve my issue.

Here is a screenshot of my application where i'm facing this problem
[dataGridView with buttoncell](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ci8fw.png)

I want to disable(or not clickable) the button if the button text says "ACCEPTED",
here is what i have and that is not working

```
        private void Cellcontent()
    {
        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
        {
            if ((row.Cells["Status"].Value.ToString()) == "ACCEPTED")
            {
                DataGridViewButtonCell cell = row.Cells["Status"] as DataGridViewButtonCell;
                cell.ReadOnly = true; //if 1 cell will be disabled (not clickable)

            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have created a small demo

https://github.com/manojsethi/DataGridViewDisableButton

Information gathered from MSDN

Hope it helps

Answer (score 2):

you could do the following if you dont mind using a a different cell when the value is not `ACCEPTED`:

```
 foreach (DataGridViewRow item in dataGridView1.Rows.OfType<DataGridViewRow>().Where(c => c.Cells[buttonCol.Index].Value != null && c.Cells[buttonCol.Index].Value.ToString() == "ACCEPTED"))
 {
     //you can replace the button with a textbox cell that contains the rejected value
     item.Cells[buttonCol.Index] = new DataGridViewTextBoxCell { Value = "ACCEPTED" }; 
     item.Cells[buttonCol.Index].ReadOnly = true;
     //note that you have to make a new button cell and replace the rejected ones if the status is updated later on to be able to use the button.
 }
```

hope this helps.

Comment: Nice Idea. Works Perfect. Thanks Bro :)